# TP-Link MR3220 3g Router not able to ping to its DDNS Address even after disabling SPF security

Tags: networking, router

I have a TP-Link MR3220 3G router. I'm using this router with a 3G USB modem to connect to the Internet.

Unfortunately I cannot ping the modem from outside to its DDNS address, even after disabling all security features like SPF filter etc. Since I cannot access this modem from outside through its DDNS address, I'm not able to use its port forwarding feature for my mail server.

I also noticed that its remote management feature through Web Console wasn't working properly either.

How can I fix this?